# Which is considered good practice in Javascript: using this or self reference?

Tags: javascript

I've seen code like this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {
        foo.baz(); // instead of this.baz();
    },
    baz: function() { ... }
}
```

Are there some problems that I might have using this approach? Will it be less error-prone than "this" (considering the fact that this might get changed from context to context)? Would it introduce any side-effects? Which should I prefer and why?

Comment: Depends on what else is done with `foo`. It's easy to make mistakes with either solution.

Comment: in this particular case I would recommend using `this` as the name of the variable can easily change but then you have to be worries about the right context :)

Comment: @georgestocker - just because someone asks if this is "good" or "bad" does NOT mean that the only possible good answers are primarily opinion-based.  Many times (such as in this case), it is possible to explain a good or bad conclusion with facts (not opinions).  This site is way too sensitive to a question that "could" be answered via an opinion when answers are certainly possible that are not primarily opinion.  And if all opinion was banned on this site such as what constitutes a good design practice or a preferred idiom, then 2/3 of the answers here would need to be banished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `foo` is a singleton (there's only one object like it and a reference to it is stored in the `foo` variable), you can do it either way.

If this was created via a constructor or factory function (thus not a singleton - such that there could be many of them), then you would certainly want to use `this` so that you were calling `baz()` with the proper object reference.

Using `foo.baz()` has an advantage when it's a singleton such that no matter how `bar()` is called (e.g. no matter what the value of `this` is when `bar()` is called, it will still properly call `foo.baz()`.

For example, if you passed `foo.bar` as a callback reference, then it would still work properly (even though `this` was set to something else).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make other objects using `foo`, using something like `Object.create()` then probably a bad idea.

---

`Object.create()`

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
  Object.create = function (o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
  };
}
newObject = oldObject.beget();
```

Read more: [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

Comment: What is `Object.beget()`?

Comment: @FelixKling: I watched a video on youtube about talk given by Douglas Crockford about JavaScript. He mentioned `Object.beget()` as better way to making objects in JavaScript in the video.

Comment: Well, that's crucial information that was missing. `Object.beget()` is not standard. The code you posted doesn't define `Object.beget()` either btw.

Comment: @FelixKling: yes it is not standard, I assumed that it is a popular way to making Objects. Thanks for pointing it out, I've posted the correct code of `Object.beget()`

Comment: Note the remark at the end of the article you linked to. `Object.create` is standard.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, TIL `Object.create`.